# jQuery Tabs not rendering in IE8 or IE7

Tags: jquery, tabs

My jQuery Tabs are not rendering in IE8 or IE7. I checked the jQuery tabs on the homepage and they seem to come up fine. This renders without a problem in all other browsers. Am I missing something IE needs? I attached an image of what it looks like in IE. Here's my code:

```
        var tabcontent1 = "<article id='tabs-min' class='tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'><ul class='ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'><li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-min-1'>Description</a></li>";
        var tabcontent2 = "<div id='tabs-min-1'><p>"+ description +"</p></div>";

        if(jQuery('.features-label').size() > 0){
            var featureslabel = jQuery(".features-label").text();
        }
        if(jQuery('.technical-label').size() > 0){
            var technicallabel = jQuery(".technical-label").text();
        }
        if(jQuery('.owners-label').size() > 0){
            var ownerslabel = jQuery(".owners-label").text();
        }
        if(jQuery('#tab_image').size() > 0){
            var imagelabel = "Image";
            var imagetext = jQuery("#tab_image").text();
        }

        if(jQuery('.features-text').size() > 0){
            var featurestext = jQuery(".features-text").html();
        }
        if(jQuery('.technical-text').size() > 0){
            var technicaltext = jQuery(".technical-text").html();
        }
        if(jQuery('.owners-text').size() > 0){
            var ownerstext = jQuery(".owners-text").html();
        }

        if (featurestext != null){
            var tabcontent1 = tabcontent1 + "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-min-2'>"+ featureslabel +"</a></li>";
            var tabcontent2 = tabcontent2 + "<div id='tabs-min-2'><p>"+ featurestext +"</p></div>";
        }
        if (technicaltext != null){
            var tabcontent1 = tabcontent1 + "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-min-3'>"+ technicallabel +"</a></li>";
            var tabcontent2 = tabcontent2 + "<div id='tabs-min-3'><p>"+ technicaltext +"</p></div>";
        }
        if (ownerstext != null){
            var tabcontent1 = tabcontent1 + "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-min-4'>"+ ownerslabel +"</a></li>";
            var tabcontent2 = tabcontent2 + "<div id='tabs-min-4'><p>"+ ownerstext +"</p></div>";
        }
        if (imagetext != null){
            var tabcontent1 = tabcontent1 + "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-min-5'>"+ imagelabel +"</a></li>";
            var tabcontent2 = tabcontent2 + "<div id='tabs-min-5'><p><img src='/v/images_tabs/"+ imagetext +"'></p></div>";
        }
        //LOAD THE TABS
            jQuery("#test123").before(tabcontent1 + "</ul>" + tabcontent2 + "</article>");
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#tabs-min" ).tabs();
});
```

[image: What it looks like in IE]

Comment: Isn't that jQuery-mobile?

Comment: Why would IE render as mobile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was "article". IE doesn't like that. Changed it to a div.

```
<article id='tabs-min'
```

Should be

```
<div id='tabs-min'
```

Comment: You could also have used HTML5 shims to keep HTML5 tags.